# Linking to a route Material-UI MenuItems

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, react-router, material-ui

I'm using Material-UI's menu components (I'm required to use their libraries)
but I'm having trouble with linking each `MenuItem` to a route I already have.

I'm temporarily using an anchor element but that is not optimal.

How can I do something similar `component={Link} to="/health"` to each `MenuItem`?

**EDIT** -- *the above line works fine if material ui is imported instead.*

**App.js**

```
class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
            return (
                <ThemeProvider>

                    <Router>
                        <div className="App-center">
                            <Route path="/" component={()=>(<div><Header/>
                                <MainMenu/></div>)}/>

                            <Route path="/health" component={HealthForm}></Route>
                        </div>
                    </Router>

                 </ThemeProvider>
            );
    }
}
```

**MainMenu.js**

```
class MainMenu extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (   
        <Menu className="App-body-menu">
            <MenuItem>
                <a href="/">Home</a>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem>
                <a href="/health">Health</a>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>   
    );
  }
}
export default MainMenu;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have the answer in your question already:

```
class MainMenu extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (   
            <Menu className="App-body-menu">
                <MenuItem component={Link} to="/">
                    Home
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem component={Link} to="health">
                    Health
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
        );
    }
}

export default MainMenu;
```

https://material-ui.com/api/menu-item/

> ### Props
>
> `component` - The component used for the root node. Either a string to use a DOM element or a component.

Comment: For some reason the MenuItems are unresponsive. Nothing happens when they are being clicked.

Comment: Yet i changed the import to material ui and it works as its supposed to, interesting.

Comment: @Dendin: I've just asked for an [official example](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/21635) of how to link to routes from MUI `MenuItem`s.

Comment: This solution creates invalid HTML, right? `<Menu />` is a `ul` element and `<MenuItem component={Link} />` creates an `a` tag which can't be a child of an unordered list.

Comment: @Adam Bohannon: If it does create invalid HTML like that, browsers don't care, it'll display just fine. If it does cause a Material-UI based problem, here's a suggested workaround: https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/routing/#list (just wrap it in another `<li>`).